# Bootstrap 3.0 responsive change and links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a portion of a page in columns of 5 that is Bootstrap responsive.  Each of those 5 sections is split up into 2 columns.  The idea is that when the container responds to be smaller, each of the 5 columns stack on top of each other, and the 2 columns stack on each other:

```
| [-][---] |  | [-][---] |  | [-][---] |  | [-][---] |  | [-][---] | 
| [-][---] |  | [-][---] |  | [-][---] |  | [-][---] |  | [-][---] |
```

becomes:

```
| [-][---] | 
| [-][---] | 
-------------
| [-][---] | 
| [-][---] | 
-------------
| [-][---] | 
| [-][---] | 
-------------
| [-][---] | 
| [-][---] | 
-------------
| [-][---] | 
| [-][---] |
```

That works fine.  My issue is that when it's horizontal, my links work, but once it becomes responsive and stacks, the links are no longer there.  Or, put more clearly, the text is there, according to Chrome's element selector, it's there, but I can't click on the link anymore.  This JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RRrLw/5/ displays the issue I'm having.

Comment: First off in your Fiddle your path to the BootStrap CSS file is incorrect (I think your looking for this path http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css) Second unless I am mistaken your fiddle doesn't accurately show the issue you are talking about above. I can click on the links (at least using Chrome). Could you fix up your fiddle and let us know what browsers you are testing with?

Comment: @crazymatt Sorry about that, I changed the JSFiddle.  Actually, I'm using the 3.0 version of Bootstrap (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`).  I've tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari for PC.

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't seem to work. Try this one instead: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/4b427/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paragraph elements are getting in front of the links. Use this CSS to bring the links in front:

```
#associated2 a{
    z-index:9;
    position:relative;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/uusux/

Comment: Awesome. That fixes that. Now for the learning process. I'm assuming that the <a> and <p> elements were basically "on top of each other". Would that be correct? I looked up what z-index is and get the idea behind it. Any specific reason why 9? I haven't played with it yet to see, but was it just through trial and error?

Comment: @Chester Yes, the were on top of each other, with the <p> elements on top. I just picked 9 because it's the highest one-digit value. You could probably use 1. I just have a habit of using high numbers.